# Ints are appearing as numpy datatypes in binary files. How do I cast these to an unsigned 8-bit integer before output

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pickle

I am writing an script that takes a list of pixels from a video and generates a binary file where each sampled pixel is represented with its index and corresponding rgb values. The issue I am having is that the RGB values generated by opencv are in some sort of numpy specific data type and I would like to cast all values in the file down to unsigned 8-bit integers to minimize file size and the amount of data that will later need to be sent across the serial connection to be shown on an RGB Neopixel strip.

I am not married to using pickle for output all I need is a binary file I can ready in byte by byte and send across the serial connection.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import pickle

# Help and args check
if((len(sys.argv) < 4) or (sys.argv[0] == "help")):
    print("This application requires 3 arguments in the following order:\n"
           + "inputVideoFile inputPixelList outputNeoPixelStream\n\n"
           + "View the README for informantion on supported formats for input files")
    exit()

# load file I/O
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(str(sys.argv[1]))
pixelFile = open(sys.argv[2], "r")
pixelStream = open(sys.argv[3], "wb")

# load pixels into 2d array
pixels = []
lines = pixelFile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    pixel = line.strip().replace(" ", "").split(",")
    pixel[0] = int(pixel[0])
    pixel[1] = int(pixel[1])
    pixels.append(pixel)
print(pixels)

#set start frame count
frameCount = 0

#set start frame
ret, frame = cap.read()
pixeldelimiter = 1
# Analyze all the video frames
while(frame is not None):
    frameCount+=1
    # Print RGB colors for each pixel that
    for index, pixel in enumerate(pixels):
        # opencv pixel format is y, x, c where c is the color in order b g r 
        r = frame[pixel[1], pixel[0], 2]
        g = frame[pixel[1], pixel[0], 1]
        b = frame[pixel[1], pixel[0], 0]

        if (r == 1): r = 0
        if (g == 1): g = 0
        if (b == 1): b = 0

        pickle.dump(pixeldelimiter, pixelStream)
        pickle.dump(index, pixelStream)
        pickle.dump(r, pixelStream)
        pickle.dump(g, pixelStream)
        pickle.dump(b, pixelStream)
    #display the current frame (useful for converting long animations)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    #load next frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
cap.release()
pixelStream.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up not using pickle and instead using struct.pack() to cast to a byte as such:

```
outputFile.write(struct.pack("B", intToCast))
```

Just be sure when you open the file to supply it with the "wb" flag rather than just "w"